Multiple branches and squash merge
Okay, so there are many questions on this site about repeatedly doing squash merges from a development branch to main. I want to ask a related question:
Suppose my feature branch A has not yet been squash merged to main, but I already want to continue working with those changes. Is there a way to start a branch B, already incorporating the changes from A, that won't cause trouble once A has been squash merged into main?

As your first sentence says, this has basically been answered many times before: once you do the squash merge, you have to use the right arguments to git rebase. You can't change the fact that a squash merge is a history rewrite, so any relationship between branches you create before that is going to become invalid. If by "won't cause trouble", you mean "won't require doing that", the only answer is to actually use git's version history by using proper merge commits, rather than throwing the history away with squash merges.

Yes, you can start working on a new branch B that incorporates changes from your feature branch A.
Here is how it will work :

Cut the branch B from branch A
git checkout A
git checkout -b B


You can continue working on branch B and once branch A is squash merged into main branch, you can take the rebase from main branch into branch B.
git checkout B
git rebase main



Rebasing branch B onto the updated main ensures that all changes from the squash merge of A are included in B

Ah, right. That crossed my mind, but was not sure whether that would go right if we were squash merging. But thanks!

I don't think git rebase main on its own will do the job here. None of the commits that were on branch A have become part of main's history, so as far as git is concerned, they are all "new" on branch B. It will attempt to recreate all of those commits on top of main. You have to use a different mode of rebase, with the --onto flag: git rebase A --onto main, which tells it that the commits you're interested in are the ones after the pointer A (which can be the old branch, or a commit hash, or any other way you want to specify the right point in history).

Which is, of course, what is explained in a load of the questions the OP already linked.
